# How do check if the templateUrl is valid in angular2?

Tags: c#, angular

I build my views using the C# Helpers and angular2 consume this view by call a controller and receiving the html of view generated by C#.
But my problem is when the user have no permissions to access the view and the controller returns 401 Unautorized, this produce a error when angular try to template load and the component stay broken until you clean cache and reload with valid authorization.

Any idea that the how can i validate templateUrl before component load ?

Comment: Maybe you could use a guard to make sure that your user has the right to access the route. For example, when the user tries to access the route loading a certain component, you are gonna make the server call to check whether your user can access the template or not.
If he has the right, the route will be active, and if not, he will be redirected elsewhere. This way, there should not be any broken situation

Comment: @AlexBeugnet Cannot do this because the guard events are performed after angular templateUrl is loaded.

Comment: This seems weird... the template should be loaded only when the route is activated. And if the guard isn't resolved, you shouldn't even reach the route...

Comment: yes, i also agree, but in my test the templateUrl is loaded before guard call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem creating a function that is call on templateUrl and return the correct string url.

```js
function hasTemplate(template: string) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('GET', template, false);
    http.send();
    return (http.status === 200) ? template : '/view/home/error/';
}

export const getViewUrl = <TModel>(modelo: { new (): TModel }, tipo: string) => {
    //Url to call web service and verify the response
    let url = `/view/${modelo.name.toLowerCase()}/${tipo}`;
    return hasTemplate(url);
};

@Component({
    selector: 'cidade-list',
    templateUrl: getViewUrl(Cidade, 'list'),
    styleUrls: [CssPath],
    providers: [
        CidadeService,
    ]
})

export class CidadeListComponent {}
```